# Get exit code of command that uses redirect operator

Tags: bash

I execute a command and redirect its output with the ">" operator.
I want to get the exit code of my command but because ">" is also considered as a command, I got the exit code of the latter.

For instance, how can I get the exit code of the yarn audit command ? Here, it would always be 0 because the ">" operator succesfully redirected the output...

```yaml
yarn audit --json > report_yarn_audit.json
EXIT_CODE=$?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This already works as intended.

```sh
$ false; echo $?
1
$ false > /dev/null; echo $?
1
$ true; echo $?
0
$ true > /dev/null; echo $?
0
$ (exit 138); echo $?
138
$ (exit 138) > /dev/null;  echo $?
138
```

What makes you think this doesn't work?

Comment: Nevermind.. I only tested using the yarn audit command that should have exited with 1 but apparently it was 0 and I miss assumed it was due to the ">" operator. I also assumed that because ">" is considered as a command, it would read the exit code of it.
Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Makes sense :-)